# How to change title Color? swift 5

Tags: swift, uikit, titlebar

I can't change title color, which is white by default and when my background color is white too, it's invisible. How can i change it to the black color?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1OFF.png)

Comment: Can you give more context? UIKit? SwiftUI?
how does current code look like?

Comment: UIKit. Just a single code
title = "Active User".
I tried this: self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.red]
and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.red]
```